# Acquiring data attribute with click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, custom-data-attribute

I am wanting to obtain a div value using a `data-attribute`. In this case specifically, `data-pdf`. As you can see within my example, after I click on either option, the value comes up undefined.

What am I doing wrong? Also, will the value change based on which heading I click on? I only want one value stored at a time.

```js
$(".pdfWrap").on("click", function (event) {
 let pdfChoice = $(this).find('.pdfWrap').data('pdf');
 console.log(pdfChoice);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pdfWrap" data-pdf="Linear Structure">
    <h3 class="pdfTitle">Linear Structure</h3>
 </div><div class="pdfWrap" data-pdf="Dynamic Structure">
    <h3 class="pdfTitle">Dynamic Structure</h3>
 </div>
```

Comment: change let pdfChoice = $(this).find('.pdfWrap').data('pdf'); to  let pdfChoice = $(this).data('pdf');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are registering the click handler on `pdfWrap` so `this` inside the callback will be `pdfWrap` element only. You dont need to do an extra `find` and instead just fetch the `data-attribute` value.

```js
$(".pdfWrap").on("click", function(event) {
  let pdfChoice = $(this).data('pdf');
  console.log(pdfChoice);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pdfWrap" data-pdf="Linear Structure">
  <h3 class="pdfTitle">Linear Structure</h3>
</div>
<div class="pdfWrap" data-pdf="Dynamic Structure">
  <h3 class="pdfTitle">Dynamic Structure</h3>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here's how you can do it without jQuery in the event handler](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset):

```js
$(".pdfWrap").on("click", function(event) {
  let pdfChoice = this.dataset.pdf;
  console.log(pdfChoice);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pdfWrap" data-pdf="Linear Structure">
  <h3 class="pdfTitle">Linear Structure</h3>
</div>
<div class="pdfWrap" data-pdf="Dynamic Structure">
  <h3 class="pdfTitle">Dynamic Structure</h3>
</div>
```